# How make a dynamic TableLayout from JSON response?

Tags: android, json, android-layout, android-tablelayout

I will make an example of a standalone application, the concept is using a `TableLayout` and data will come from a webserver(in JSON). There will be strings, images, `RadioButton` and CheckBox` inside it. For more details, here the image:

[image]

and:

[image]

How can I make this dynamically?

Comment: is your application, a native app or does it use some HTML?

Comment: And where exactly do you encounter problems? The TableLayout construction is simple if you know the structure of the `json` response.